# DateTime.TryParse uses wrong format for MSA

Tags: sql-server, datetime, c#-3.0, sqlclr, regional-settings

A c# sqlclr function containing DateTime.TryParse isn't returning the correct date on a new windows server. The date and regional settings were in US format on this server instead of GB and the sql server is using a managed service account.

I installed the English (United Kingdom) language pack and deleted the old one. Updated the regional settings for the UK date format and used the Administrative tab in the control panel regional settings to copy the settings to the welcome screen, system accounts and new users.

UK date parsing still does not work. Calling the function manually in powershell under my user account returns the correct value.

I tried changing the registry settings under the MSA account to match my current user based on this list but still no success.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/08/16/how-to-change-regional-settings-for-all-users-on-a-computer/

SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU6) on Windows Server 2016 build 14393

Answer (score 2):

To update the regional settings of the managed service account (without recreating it) perform the following.

1. Run powershell using [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) from sysinternals. Leave the password blank and press enter. cmd would also work but powershell lets you easily test the function.

   & 'psexec.exe' -u domain\msa$ -i powershell
2. Add the dll and check the function result.

   Add-Type -Path "path\clr.dll"
   [TypeConverter]::ftn_ConvertToDate("20/10/2017 00:00");
3. Incorrect result returned. Run `intl.cpl` in powershell. This will open the regional settings as the msa user. Set the format to English (United Kingdom) or another format as needed. This will change the settings for the MSA that the powershell session is run for.
4. Test again to see the correct result.

   [TypeConverter]::ftn_ConvertToDate("20/10/2017 00:00");
5. Restart the SQL Service and the clr function will use the new date format.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for posting this info (+1). Should #3 have a little more explanation? I don't do much with PowerShell and am not entirely sure where to find intl.cpl, etc. Maybe post the command to execute for that step? Also, quick question: if you are using SQL Server 2017, why not use the built-in T-SQL `TRY_PARSE` function? It does use the same underlying .NET method.

Comment: Yeah, I'll elaborate on that. Just wanted to get it in while I had time. I thought the same thing after receiving the functions but the sqlclr performed significantly faster. I surmise it's because it does 3 try_parse calls for 3 dates and compiling it into 1 is better than 3 individual transitions to clr. Haven't proved it yet but it was very interesting to see the difference.

Comment: I assume you have it marked as `IsDeterministic=true`? Also, while I haven't tested on SQL Server 2017 (and maybe not even 2016), I do seem to recall that even `String.Format` via SQLCLR was slightly faster than the T-SQL built-in `FORMAT` command (starting in 2012?) that calls the same underlying method. Interesting indeed :)